# HTML 5 defer attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to understand `async` & `defer` HTML 5 attributes. Here is my testing code:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" **defer**></script>
    <div id="div1">
        Abc
    </div>  
</body>
```

script.js:

```
document.write("Hello World!")
```

As I understand, and according to the definition, "defer ... specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing" shouldn't the output be:

```
Abc
Hello World!
```

instead of

```
Abc
```

which is the case?

Why does the `document.write()` not work with defer?

The answer "document.write clears page" doesn't take into account defer attribute. The resulting final answer is similar but my question was asked from another perspective.

Comment: It may be a simple lack of support, but I'm not confident enough to consider that as an answer, but MDN offers: "*Since this feature hasn't yet been implemented by all other major browsers, authors should not assume that the script’s execution will actually be deferred.*" – [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).

Comment: @DavidThomas The `<script>` has the `src` attribute.

Comment: You should use other methods to add content to a document. The worst you could do is `document.body.innerHTML += 'Hello World!';` and would be better than `document.write()`. At least, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open the JavaScript console on Chrome you will see the following message:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Not executing the `document.write` from deferred (asynchronous) script makes sense. Take into account this:

- `defer` indicates the browser to wait and execute the code when the document has been loaded and parsed.
- `document.write` writes to the document stream.
- If `document.write` is called when the document is closed (loaded), then `document.open` is automatically called, the document is cleared and replaced with the content of `document.write`.

Preventing the execution of `document.write` within a deferred script will prevent the page/document from being cleared and only showing the content of the `document.write`.

---

Also there would be the question of "where should the content be written?" In your question you expect a result of `Abc Hello World`, but I would expect `Hello World Abc` as I would still expect the content to be written right after the `script` tag instead of at the end of the document.

It would be better to use a different method that will be supported in asynchronous cases and that will give you control over where the content will be placed, like for example `appendChild` or `insertBefore`.