# setTimeout and synchronization

Tags: javascript

Having the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
```

script.js:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("first");
}, 15);
```

script2.js:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("second");
}, 10);
```

while running it I got different results. One time the output is:

```
second
first
```

but another time:

```
first
second
```

Shouldn't it be always in the "second, first" order due to given time delay?

Comment: I assume OP wants to say, he has 2 `setTimeout` and wants to synchronize them.

Comment: Given [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719149/html-5-defer-attribute), are you just learning, or are perhaps both of these questions an attempt at a solution for an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - do you have an underlying question/problem that you want to solve?

Comment: @ James Thorpe - corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple race condition.

The spec guarantees that the script files run in order.  That means that the browser is free to attempt to download the files at the same time, but even if script2.js loads before script.js, script.js will run first.

However, if script.js loads quickly and is executed while script2.js is still downloading from the server, there is a chance that at least 5ms will pass before script2.js is executed.  If that happens, the timeout in script.js will be executed first, and the output will be `first, second`.

Comment: @ James Thorpe: So the browser downloads the scripts in separate, un-synchronized threads while execution is synchronized to first run script 1 and when finished script 2?

Comment: @Mulligan81 essentially, yes.  But if script2 hasn't finished downloading yet, it can't execute it, meanwhile the timeout in script1 is already ticking away

Answer (score 0):

I have three way to solve your question.

1. Call first function in second function.

   ```
   function first(){
       second();
       setTimeout(function(){
           console.log("first");
       }, 10);
   }

   function second(){
       setTimeout(function(){
           console.log("second");
       }, 10);
   }
   ```
2. Just give a more interval to First function.

   ```
   function first(){
       setTimeout(function(){
           console.log("first");
       }, 11);
   }

   function second(){
       setTimeout(function(){
           console.log("second");
       }, 10);
   }
   ```
3. Use Flag.

   ```
   var flag = false; //global variable

   function first(){
       setTimeout(function(){
           if(flag){
               console.log("first");
           }else{
               first();
           }
       }, 10);
   }

   function second(){
       flag = true;
       setTimeout(function(){
           console.log("second");
       }, 10);
   }
   ```